# Sorbet: how do you add a signature for a dynamically generated method?

Tags: sorbet

I'm using https://github.com/kenn/active_flag and https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/sorbet-rails

This is what its rbi looks like:

```
module ActiveFlag
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
class ActiveFlag::Definition
  def column; end
  def human(key, options = nil); end
  def humans; end
  def initialize(column, keys, klass); end
  def keys; end
  def maps; end
  def pairs; end
  def set_all!(key); end
  def to_array(integer); end
  def to_i(arg); end
  def to_value(instance, integer); end
  def unset_all!(key); end
end
class ActiveFlag::Railtie < Rails::Railtie
end
class ActiveFlag::Value < Set
  def method_missing(symbol, *args, &block); end
  def raw; end
  def set!(key, options = nil); end
  def set(key); end
  def set?(key); end
  def to_human; end
  def to_s; end
  def unset!(key, options = nil); end
  def unset(key); end
  def unset?(key); end
  def with(instance, definition); end
end
module ActiveFlag::ClassMethods
  def flag(column, keys); end
end
class ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActiveFlag::ClassMethods
end
```

The last bit (extending AR::Base) I added, the rest `srb rbi gems` generated automatically.

To actually use Active Flag, I then do this in my model:

`flag :visible_to, [:employee, :manager, :admin]`

`visible_to` is an integer column. Sorbet Rails has already typed it as such:

```
  sig { returns(Integer) }
  def visible_to; end

  sig { params(value: Integer).void }
  def visible_to=(value); end

  sig { returns(T::Boolean) }
  def visible_to?; end
```

I *could* change this definition, but it's an autogenerated file and I assume the changes will get lost. So the next thing I tried was adding a sig directly above where the method gets used:

```
  sig { returns(ActiveFlag::Value) }
  def visible_to; end
  flag :visible_to, [:employee, :manager, :admin]
```

The problem here is that Sorbet fails because the method I've "defined" doesn't return anything. Which I know is fine, because it'll get overriden when `flag` is called (it uses `define_method` internally), but I don't know how to communicate this to Sorbet.

```
Returning value that does not conform to method result type https://srb.help/7005
    54 |  def visible_to; end
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Expected ActiveFlag::Value
    Method visible_to has return type ActiveFlag::Value
    54 |  def visible_to; end
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Got NilClass originating from:
    54 |  def visible_to; e
```

So my question is. What's the best way to tell Sorbet that this method will return an `ActiveFlag::Value` once it gets defined, ideally without making a manual change to an autogenerated file?

btw. I tried to see how types for `enum` in Rails are handled... it doesn't look like that's been done on `sorbet-typed` yet. Possibly for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to override a generated `rbi` file you can create a second `rbi` file for the same class in your workspace and move the methods in there. Sorbet will handle merging multiple definitions files for you. We keep these files in a separate `sorbet/custom` directory next to the generated files; others keep the `rbi` files next to the `rb` files in their application directory.

As to enums, Sorbet does not natively support enum literal types so that's likely why.

Comment: I didn't realise you can put .rbis next to .rbs. That's a neat idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom plugin for `sorbet-rails` to generate methods added by `active_flag` and remove the sigs generated wrongly. Here is the documentation for it:

https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/sorbet-rails/blob/master/README.md#extending-model-generation-task-with-custom-plugins